# <footer> in my html code is not working correctly and is overlapping the <main>

Tags: html, css

I am pretty new to coding and I am doing this for my online college class. For some reason, my footer is not going to the bottom. Neglect the navigation bar above.

I also need more words to post this so I'm going to keep adding word until it says I am fine. So yeah I keep talking and talking and talking well actually I'm typing and not talking so I'm typing typing typing until this post says I have enough words because this code is pretty big.

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #e1b382;
  color: #e1b382;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color: #2d545e;
  background-image: url(lilyheader.jpg);
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

nav {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

main nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 198px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #2d545e;
}

main nav a {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: -20px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2%;
  padding: 2%;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: #2d545e;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #e1b382;
  background-color: #2d545e;
}

.search {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  ;
  padding-left: calc(2%);
  padding-right: calc(18%);
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: #2d545e;
}

.search:hover {
  color: #e1b382;
  background-color: #2d545e;
}

footer {
  background-color: #2d545e;
  font-size: .60em;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 1em;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 1000px;
  min-width: 900px;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

main {
  display: block;
  color: #2d545e;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.floatright {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 400px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

main li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Georgia;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

h2 {
  padding-left: 2em;
}

.borderdiv {
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #e1b382;
}

main div div div img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px outset #e1b382
}

main div div div img:hover {
  border: 1px inset #2d545e
}

main a {
  color: #2d545e;
}

section {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

.bar {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -29px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 300px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.pic {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}

.item {
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ONSHOP Online Store and Shipping :: Items</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="research.css">
  <!--Reed Wilson-->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>ONSHOP</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="items.html">Items</a>
      <a>Ordered</a>
      <a>Sale</a>
      <a>Saved</a>
      <a>Login</a>
      <a>Watchlist</a>
      <a>Help</a>
      <a class="search">Search</a>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <h2 style="margin-left:25px">Items</h2>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Clothes</a></li>
          <li><a>Food</a></li>
          <li><a>Home</a></li>
          <li><a>Toys</a></li>
          <li><a>Sports</a></li>
          <li><a>Animal Care</a></li>
          <li><a>Electronics</a></li>
          <li><a>Kitchen</a></li>
          <li><a>Office</a></li>
          <li><a>Music</a></li>
          <li><a>Toiletries</a></li>
          <li><a>Filter</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <section>
        <div>
          <p class="bar">Search</p>
        </div>
        <div class="borderdiv">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="pic">
              <img src="shopping-6.jpg" alt="Home">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h6>Lysol Hand Sanitizer 4 Pack</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="pic">
              <img src="shopping-3.jpg" alt="Home">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h6>Clorox Disinfecting Wipes</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <p>Copyright &copy; 2020 Design of a Major Website<br>
        <a href="mailto:reed@wilson.com">reed@wilson.com</a></p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you set float:left;width:100%; in all row section

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to provide `height` to the `main` class, provide how much height you need.

```
main{
     height:800px; //just an example height.
    }
```

Please find the code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #e1b382;
  color: #e1b382;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color: #2d545e;
  background-image: url(lilyheader.jpg);
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

nav {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

main{
  height:800px;
}

main nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 198px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #2d545e;
}

main nav a {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: -20px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2%;
  padding: 2%;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: #2d545e;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #e1b382;
  background-color: #2d545e;
}

.search {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  ;
  padding-left: calc(2%);
  padding-right: calc(18%);
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: #2d545e;
}

.search:hover {
  color: #e1b382;
  background-color: #2d545e;
}

footer {
  background-color: #2d545e;
  font-size: .60em;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 1em;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  
}

#wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 1000px;
  min-width: 900px;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

main {
  display: block;
  color: #2d545e;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.floatright {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 400px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

main li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Georgia;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

h2 {
  padding-left: 2em;
}

.borderdiv {
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #e1b382;
}

main div div div img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px outset #e1b382
}

main div div div img:hover {
  border: 1px inset #2d545e
}

main a {
  color: #2d545e;
}

section {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

.bar {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -29px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 300px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.pic {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}

.item {
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ONSHOP Online Store and Shipping :: Items</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="research.css">
  <!--Reed Wilson-->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>ONSHOP</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="items.html">Items</a>
      <a>Ordered</a>
      <a>Sale</a>
      <a>Saved</a>
      <a>Login</a>
      <a>Watchlist</a>
      <a>Help</a>
      <a class="search">Search</a>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <h2 style="margin-left:25px">Items</h2>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Clothes</a></li>
          <li><a>Food</a></li>
          <li><a>Home</a></li>
          <li><a>Toys</a></li>
          <li><a>Sports</a></li>
          <li><a>Animal Care</a></li>
          <li><a>Electronics</a></li>
          <li><a>Kitchen</a></li>
          <li><a>Office</a></li>
          <li><a>Music</a></li>
          <li><a>Toiletries</a></li>
          <li><a>Filter</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <section>
        <div>
          <p class="bar">Search</p>
        </div>
        <div class="borderdiv">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="pic">
              <img src="shopping-6.jpg" alt="Home">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h6>Lysol Hand Sanitizer 4 Pack</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="pic">
              <img src="shopping-3.jpg" alt="Home">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h6>Clorox Disinfecting Wipes</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <p>Copyright &copy; 2020 Design of a Major Website<br>
        <a href="mailto:reed@wilson.com">reed@wilson.com</a></p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `float:left` in for left nav. That's why the height of that container is not being calculated and your footer showing in the middle.

Remove `float:left`, use `display: inline-block` for left nav and section with `vertical-align:top`. Avoid using fixed height in not necessary.

Below is the corrected code snippet.

```css
    body {
      background-color: #e1b382;
      color: #e1b382;
      font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    header {
      background-color: #2d545e;
      background-image: url(lilyheader.jpg);
      background-position: right;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 150px;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
    }

    h1 {
      padding-top: 50px;
    }

    nav {
      font-weight: bold;
      padding-top: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    main nav {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align:top;
      width: 198px;
      margin-left: 75px;
      border: 1px solid #2d545e;
    }

    main nav a {
      float: left;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: -20px;
    }

    nav a {
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 2%;
      padding: 2%;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding-top: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      color: #2d545e;
    }

    nav a:hover {
      color: #e1b382;
      background-color: #2d545e;
    }

    .search {
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      ;
      padding-left: calc(2%);
      padding-right: calc(18%);
      padding-top: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      color: #2d545e;
    }

    .search:hover {
      color: #e1b382;
      background-color: #2d545e;
    }

    footer {
      background-color: #2d545e;
      font-size: .60em;
      text-align: center;
      font-style: italic;
      padding: 1em;
      display: block;
      bottom: 0;
    }

    #wrapper {
      width: 80%;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      background-color: white;
      min-height: 1000px;
      min-width: 900px;
      max-width: 1200px;
    }

    main {
      display: block;
      color: #2d545e;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }

    .floatright {
      float: right;
      margin-left: 400px;
    }

    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    main li {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 200px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Arial, Georgia;
    }

    .column {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
      padding-bottom: 3px;
    }

    .row::after {
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: table;
    }

    h2 {
      padding-left: 2em;
    }

    .borderdiv {
      float: left;
      width: calc(50% - 2px);
      padding-bottom: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #e1b382;
    }

    main div div div img {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 50%;
      border: 1px outset #e1b382
    }

    main div div div img:hover {
      border: 1px inset #2d545e
    }

    main a {
      color: #2d545e;
    }

    section {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align:top;
    }

    .bar {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-top: -29px;
      height: 30px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 300px;
      border: 1px solid gray;
    }

    .pic {
      width: 30%;
      float: left;
    }

    .item {
      width: 70%;
      float: right;
    }
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>ONSHOP Online Store and Shipping :: Items</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="research.css">
      <!--Reed Wilson-->
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
          <h1>ONSHOP</h1>
        </header>
        <nav>
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
          <a href="items.html">Items</a>
          <a>Ordered</a>
          <a>Sale</a>
          <a>Saved</a>
          <a>Login</a>
          <a>Watchlist</a>
          <a>Help</a>
          <a class="search">Search</a>
        </nav>
        <main>
          <h2 style="margin-left:25px">Items</h2>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a>Clothes</a></li>
              <li><a>Food</a></li>
              <li><a>Home</a></li>
              <li><a>Toys</a></li>
              <li><a>Sports</a></li>
              <li><a>Animal Care</a></li>
              <li><a>Electronics</a></li>
              <li><a>Kitchen</a></li>
              <li><a>Office</a></li>
              <li><a>Music</a></li>
              <li><a>Toiletries</a></li>
              <li><a>Filter</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <section>
            <div>
              <p class="bar">Search</p>
            </div>
            <div class="borderdiv">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="pic">
                  <img src="shopping-6.jpg" alt="Home">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <h6>Lysol Hand Sanitizer 4 Pack</h6>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="pic">
                  <img src="shopping-3.jpg" alt="Home">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <h6>Clorox Disinfecting Wipes</h6>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </main>
        <footer>
          <p>Copyright &copy; 2020 Design of a Major Website<br>
            <a href="mailto:reed@wilson.com">reed@wilson.com</a></p>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made an edit to your code and it works. the problem was tha you have used float for your elements and you did not make a "clearfix" element for them.

```css
body {
  background-color: #e1b382;
  color: #e1b382;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color: #2d545e;
  background-image: url(lilyheader.jpg);
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

nav {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

main nav {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 198px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #2d545e;
}

main nav a {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: -20px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2%;
  padding: 2%;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: #2d545e;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #e1b382;
  background-color: #2d545e;
}

.search {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: calc(2%);
  padding-right: calc(18%);
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: #2d545e;
}

.search:hover {
  color: #e1b382;
  background-color: #2d545e;
}

footer {
  background-color: #2d545e;
  font-size: .60em;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 1em;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 1000px;
  min-width: 900px;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

main {
  display: block;
  color: #2d545e;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.floatright {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 400px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

main li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Georgia;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

h2 {
  padding-left: 2em;
}

.borderdiv {
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #e1b382;
}

main div div div img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px outset #e1b382
}

main div div div img:hover {
  border: 1px inset #2d545e
}

main a {
  color: #2d545e;
}

section {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

.bar {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -29px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 300px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.pic {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}

.item {
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ONSHOP Online Store and Shipping :: Items</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="research.css">
  <!--Reed Wilson-->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>ONSHOP</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="items.html">Items</a>
      <a>Ordered</a>
      <a>Sale</a>
      <a>Saved</a>
      <a>Login</a>
      <a>Watchlist</a>
      <a>Help</a>
      <a class="search">Search</a>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <h2 style="margin-left:25px">Items</h2>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Clothes</a></li>
          <li><a>Food</a></li>
          <li><a>Home</a></li>
          <li><a>Toys</a></li>
          <li><a>Sports</a></li>
          <li><a>Animal Care</a></li>
          <li><a>Electronics</a></li>
          <li><a>Kitchen</a></li>
          <li><a>Office</a></li>
          <li><a>Music</a></li>
          <li><a>Toiletries</a></li>
          <li><a>Filter</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <section>
        <div>
          <p class="bar">Search</p>
        </div>
        <div class="borderdiv">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="pic">
              <img src="shopping-6.jpg" alt="Home">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h6>Lysol Hand Sanitizer 4 Pack</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="pic">
              <img src="shopping-3.jpg" alt="Home">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h6>Clorox Disinfecting Wipes</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <p>Copyright &copy; 2020 Design of a Major Website<br>
        <a href="mailto:reed@wilson.com">reed@wilson.com</a></p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```